# Why is Gunicorn only working when flask is installed outside of virtualenv?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I am deploying a Flask based web application on an ubuntu 14.04 VPS. I'm basically following the instructions that I found at Real Python [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/). Previously when I have started up gunicorn I get the message: "ImportError: No module named flask"; this is in spite of making sure that flask is installed in the virtualenv and having removed it and reinstalled it serveral times as well as deactivating and reactivating virtualenv as well as removing and then reinstalling the virtualenv.

At my wits end I thought I'd install flask whilst the virtualenv was deactviated and viola! gunicorn runs without issue. I then thought that I would start up gunicorn outside of virtualenv and I've found that that it works even when virtualenv is off.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

The gunicorn command that I am running is:

```
gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000
```

I am running this command from within the project folder which contains the file app.py which contains the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return 'Flask is running!'


@app.route('/data')
def names():
   data = {"names": ["John", "Jacob", "Julie", "Jennifer"]}
   return jsonify(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run() code here
```

Comment: Can you post the command you're having gunicorn run? As well as some sample code?  The most helpful code will be wherever you declare your app object.

Comment: Hi, I've added the gunicorn command as well as the code where the app object is declared.

Comment: Ensure that the gunicorn you're running is the one that is installed in your virtualenv.  Try `which gunicorn` and I suspect it will point you to the gunicorn you have installed with your global python install instead of the one in your virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, will try this

Comment: Looks like it's working, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the gunicorn you're running is the one that is installed in your virtualenv. Try which gunicorn and I suspect it will point you to the gunicorn you have installed with your global python install instead of the one in your virtualenv.